# which data structure to use for getting all numbers less than a given number

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Which data structure is most appropriate for queries like insertion, deletion and getting all the elements
whose value is less than a given number. BST or Priority Queue? or any other data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BST seems like the one you need. Insertion, deletion with O(h) complexity. Getting all the elements less than a given number is also O(h), you just need a preorder traversal to find the node of whole left tree.

h is the height of the tree.

If you want to be more stable, maintain an AVL gives you O(logn) complexity over BST.